# Multiple condition with ternary operator

Tags: thymeleaf

With spring boot 3 and thymeleaf, I have

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'genericForm'+${genericForm.field}" th:attr="data-msg=#{form.mandatory.field}, name=${genericForm.field}" required/>
```

I try to write data-inputmask in thymleaf, but the 99-9999999 and name is dynamic. If the mask is null i don't want write the data-input part. So I need to be able to combine multiple condition

```
<input data-inputmask="'mask': '99-9999999'" name="test"/>
```

Can't say if it's possible to do it without if condition, only with ternary operator

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'genericForm'+${genericForm.field}" th:attr="${genericForm.formatter!=null} ? 'data-inputmask=mask:' ${genericForm.formatter} : '' , name=${genericForm.field}" required/>
```

Could be nice if i can put required like a variable...

actually, i use a condition around the input

```
<div th:if="${genericForm.mandatory}" th:remove="tag">
```